# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in OpenWeather Api Call

Tags: ajax, api, openweathermap

I'm putting together my first Api project and I'm using OpenWeather to request conditions for a city. When I run my code, I get "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED." I've checked and rechecked my URL formatting and I'm not getting any errors when running my code. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**My HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="./js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Weatherd</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Weatherd</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by city"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    <main>
        <p>Weather for</p>
        <p id="weatherFor"></p>
        
        <p>Temperature: </p>
        <p id ="temp"></p>
        
        <p>Currently feels like: </p>
        <p id="feelsLike"></p>
        
        <p>Conditions: </p>
        <p id="desc"></p>
</main>  
</body>
</html>
```

**My JS**

```
const $weatherFor = $('#weatherFor');
const $temp = $('#temp');
const $feelsLike = $('#feelsLike');
const $desc = $('#desc');
const $input = $('input[type="text"]');
let weatherData, userInput;
$('form').on('submit', handleGetData);
function handleGetData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    userInput = $input.val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+userInput+'&APPID=15ff99dd07f18bda25869ab24d06891e'
    }).then(
        (data) => {
            weatherData = data;
            render();
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log('bad request', error);
        }
    );
}
function render() {
    $weatherFor.text(weatherData.weatherFor);
    $temp.text(weatherData.temp);
    $feelsLike.text(weatherData.feelsLike);
    $desc.text(weatherData.desc);

 }
```

Comment: I believe that's a DNS error.  Are you able to open the ajax request url in your browser ok?

Comment: yes, I just tried hard coding in the city request with the api key and it worked. I've also moved userInput to after the URL and no longer get the error. I am getting a 'bad request' now, so sorting that now. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question was asked, but given the amount of visits this question has had so far, this answer might help someone.

```
const url = "api_url_here";
const result = await axios
  .get(url)
  .then((res) => {
    const { status } = res;
    return status && status == 200
      ? { ...res.data, status: 200 } // return data + status 200
      : { status: 400 }; // create and return status 400 on error
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return { status: 400 }; // create and return status 400 on error
  });

// work with the returned status
if(result.status == 200) {
  // success
} else {
  // error
}
```

I used axios, but the idea is very much transferable to Fetch Api or Ajax.